# Composite Gauss Legendre quadrature

Tags: calculus, integration, legendre-polynomials

I am studying Gauss Legendre quadrature. I understand the concept and the specifics values that we need to use when applying the formula.

However I am trying to understand if it is possible to integrate a function using the Gauss Legendre method over a certain interval but with a specific step size h,( divided in intervals), as we can do when using another quadrature method.

Basically I am confusing because I cannot find any formula but I read somewhere that if we increase the N ( number of intervals) the result will be more accurate. So is there any Composite Gauss Legendre formula as we have for  Composite Simpson method for example?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just split the interval $I = [a,b]$ over which you want to integrate and apply a certain Gauss-Legendre formula over each subinterval. There is no such thing as a closed formula as in the case of Newton-Cotes.

Comment: Hi I do not understand. I know that I have to map the interval [a,b] to the interval [-1,1] and then apply the formula using the weights and the correspondent x nodes in the formula, but if for example I have the interval [1,5] and I want to split the interval in 5 (N=5) what should I do? I cannot find exercises to help me to understand this. Can you help on this? Or do you know any website that I can find more information? thanks

Comment: @user290335 You split your interval $[1,5]$ into for example $[1,3]$, $[3,4]$ and $[4,5]$ and then apply on each interval the Gauss-Legendre formula separately and add the results together.

Comment: So every time I subdivide the interval into [1,3],[3,4] etc. as you said I need to map that interval to the interval [-1,1] and use the new function that I need to integrate by mapping the intervals? And if I have N=200? will be the same or is there any other way?